# xcode document outline has extra content view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am learning objective c and I'm following this tutorial here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Whenever I create a table cell view, It creates an extra content view that makes it impossible to link my labels, images to the cell.  How Can I delete the extra content view and link my objects?

Here is a screenshot showing what I mean...

[image]

Getting an Error with this code... use of undeclared identifier on cell.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

MingleViewCell *cell = (MingleViewCell *)[[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MingleViewCell"]];
LocalPerson *local = [self.people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.nameLabel.text = local.name;
cell.aboutMeLabel.text = local.game;
return cell;
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by this `it impossible to link my labels, images to the cell`

Comment: on the tutorial it says "Now you can connect the labels and the image view to these outlets. Either select the label and drag from its Connections Inspector to the table view cell, or do it the other way around, ctrl-drag from the table view cell back to the label:" but I can't because it doesn't let me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relax. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html):
`The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.`

This is how it's done, the content view should be there and you should be able to connect IBOutlets/IBActions normally by ctrl-dragging from your elements added to the cell in the storyboard into the custom cell class code.

Comment: Did you set the cell identifier as `MingleViewCell` in the storyboard? If not, then that's the problem.

Comment: Then perhaps you should consider asking a new question with more details about your current problem, because this problem seems to be unrelated to your original question about the content view.

Answer (score 0):

you should not delete the content view which you are calling is extra. If you see UITableViewCell has a property contentView by default in which you add all the other content like UIButton, UILabel, etc. It's this contentView which is the main container.

So whenever you inherit any class from UITableViewCell, that class also has this contentView. So instead of deleting it you can use it as a container and add other elements.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm just confused because I'm still getting an error.